# How to show selectpicker when it ready?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select, bootstrap-4

I have a select on my page, for customization I use the selectpicker plugin. When the page loads, the area where the select should appear looks [unacceptable](http://img.netpeak.ua/dron/2022-11-06_365520.png) for a while. How to display a select only when it has already been rendered by the selectpicker?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Vlastelin/pen/xxzERRr)

```js
$(function () {
    $('select').selectpicker();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<select class="selectpicker">
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Barbecue</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<select class="selectpicker" name="selectpicker">
  <option value="mustard">Mustard</option>
  <option value="ketchup">Ketchup</option>
  <option value="barbecue">Barbecue</option>
</select>

$(function () {
    var selected=document.getElementsByName('selectpicker');
    console.log(selected);
});
```